# Do adamantine short swords, daggers, rapiers...etc keep their finesse properties?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, special-materials

I remember that in past editions adamantine is a heavy and sturdy metal. It allows the creation of excellent armors and even better weapons. I just want to know that if the finesse property still holds when the weapon is forged or created via the [*Fabricate*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fabricate) spell when adamantine is used.

Comment: Is there anything in the current rules that would make you think it makes weapons lose the finesse property?

Comment: Jhyarelle, **do not** simply delete and re-post your question to get around question closure. You have been repeatedly asked to put more effort into researching and reviewing your questions prior to posting, failing to do so will get your questions closed. You have been around more than long enough to know what the expectations are. Delete/re-post is not a work around for low-quality posts. Consider this a formal warning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Nothing would remove the finesse property

It's a hard substance, but not heavy. If you look at *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* (p. 78), it says of [adamantine weapons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/xgte/dungeon-masters-tools#AdamantineWeapons):

> Adamantine is an ultrahard metal found in meteorites and extraordinary mineral veins. [...] Melee weapons and ammunition made of or coated with adamantine are unusually effective when used to break objects.

Nothing in the description would indicate that it changes any properties.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Nothing about adamantine says anything about it changing any of a weapon’s properties, so it doesn’t.

Also, as far as I know, adamantine has never made items heavier or more cumbersome, in any edition of D&D. I have attempted to find such a thing without success. Most editions instead say that it is exactly as dense as steel.